# Layout imagens em carousel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, carousel

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código :

```
var images = [];

for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < actions[i].Images.length; j++) {

        var imagem = new Image();
        imagem.Description = actions[i].Images[j].Description;
        imagem.Url = actions[i].Images[j].Url;
        images.push(imagem);
    }
}

$('#carousel-imagens').append($("#imagesTemplate").tmpl(images));
$('#carousel-imagens').addClass("item");
```

O `array` var images armazena as `URL` de várias imagens que tenho. Porém ao passar esse `array` pro `carousel`, ele coloca as imagens uma embaixo da outra. Gostaria que fossem colocadas ao lado, o que devo fazer ?

Comment: Daí quem vai mandar nisso é seu CSS.

Comment: O bootstrap monta o layout

Comment: Você está usando algum plugin do Bootstrap para montar o Carousel? Dá uma olhada nesse tutorial, veja se te ajuda: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

Comment: Esse exemplo mesmo que estou seguindo. mas as imagens não estão ao lado como no exemplo. estão ficando uma embaixo da outra

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira :

```
$('#carousel-imagens > div.item:eq(0)').addClass("active");
```

Apenas a primeira imagem deve receber a classe `active`, e as seguintes não. Da forma que eu estava fazendo todas as imagens recebiam o `active`, portanto eram exibidas uma embaixo da outra.